# Check the availability of a specific queue in ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic

Is there any way I can check the whether a specific queue already exists or not in ActiveMQ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will have to be a bit more specific if you want a concrete example: do you want to do it with a Web Console, JMX or programmatically. `ActiveMQ` btw creates queues on demand, whenever you need one, not like WebSphere MQ where you will get an exception if the queue does not exist.

Comment: I would be happy if you can come with a programmatic approach for that end, please.

Comment: @Maoritzio I would be happy if I had a Mercedes W219.. Create a new question of what EXACTLY u want ;)

Comment: This is the accepted answer, but it doesn't answer the question, just points out a flaw in the question. Rather than post an answer, @Eugene really should have asked for this refinement in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 4):

http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-topics-and-queues-in-a-broker.html